# Query group by and order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

From this query:

```
SELECT 
  v.idutente AS idutente, 
  vl.idvideo AS idvideo, 
  (vl.likeY-vl.unlikeY) AS sott 
FROM video_likeunlike AS vl 
LEFT OUTER JOIN video AS v 
ON vl.idvideo = v.ID 
WHERE status = '1'
```

I have this data from table

```
idutente   idvideo   likeY      unlikeY    sott 
------------------------------------------------
1             70       2          5         -3
2             81       6          10        -4
1             52      200         198        2
1             54       30         2         28
2             67       20         5         15
3             22       12         0         12
```

I need this result, is possible?

```
idutente   likeY      unlikeY    sott 
------------------------------------------------
1           232         205        27
2           26          15         11
3           12           0         12
```

I try with this query

```
SELECT 
  v.idutente AS idutente, 
  vl.idvideo AS idvideo, 
  vl.likeY as likeY, 
  vl.unlikeY as unlikeY, 
  (vl.likeY-vl.unlikeY) AS sott 
FROM video_likeunlike AS vl 
LEFT OUTER JOIN video AS v 
ON vl.idvideo = v.ID 
WHERE status = '1' 
GROUP BY v.idutente 
ORDER BY sott DESC
```

Comment: You are using 2 tables in your try query but you listed only 1 table in question.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the aggregate SUM() operation for the select columns. The query can be modified as:

```
SELECT v.idutente AS idutente,
       vl.idvideo AS idvideo,
       SUM(vl.likeY) AS likeY,
       SUM(vl.unlikeY) AS unlikeY,
       SUM(vl.likeY-vl.unlikeY) AS sott
FROM video_likeunlike AS vl
LEFT OUTER JOIN video AS v ON vl.idvideo = v.ID
WHERE status = '1'
GROUP BY v.idutente
ORDER BY sott DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use the sql [sum()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function

```
SELECT 
  v.idutente AS idutente, 
  sum(vl.likeY) as likeY, 
  sum(vl.unlikeY) as unlikeY, 
  sum(vl.likeY)-sum(vl.unlikeY) AS sott 
FROM video_likeunlike AS vl 
LEFT OUTER JOIN video AS v 
ON vl.idvideo = v.ID 
WHERE status = '1' 
GROUP BY v.idutente 
ORDER BY sott DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT idutente, 
  SUM(likeY) likeY, 
  SUM(unlikeY) unlikeY, 
  SUM(sott) sott
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY idutente
ORDER BY sott DESC
```

Try it in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/628a8/2).

Answer (score 0):

Use your first query as a sub-query and do the group by.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.idutente, SUM(t.likeY) as likeY, SUM(t.unlikeY) as unlikeY from(
    SELECT 
      v.idutente AS idutente, 
      vl.idvideo AS idvideo, 
      vl.likeY,
      vl.unlikeY,
      (vl.likeY-vl.unlikeY) AS sott 
    FROM video_likeunlike AS vl 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN video AS v 
    ON vl.idvideo = v.ID 
    WHERE status = '1'
) t
GROUP BY t.idutente
ORDER t.sott desc;
```